# What is the correct way to add Javascript as of Joomla 3.x?

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript

I'd like to know the 'currently' correct way to add JavaScript to the head of a page. The [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page) suggests using `$document->addStyleSheet($url);`, but the [API documentation](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Document.Document.html#method_addScript) says that this method is deprecated.

There is also the `JHTML::_('script','path','options')` method, but the first piece of documentation I referred to says that this is deprecated and was removed in 3, even though it still works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method itself isn't deprecated, only the format of the function parameters.

**Earlier Joomla versions (deprecated):**

```
$doc->addScript($url, $mime, $defer, $async)
```

**Later Joomla versions:**

```
$doc->addScript($url, $options, $attributes)
```

I'm not sure what the `JHtml` deprecation notice is about but it shouldn't affect what you're trying to do.

So to answer you actual question, the correct way to add Javascript to your site will be as following:

**General:**

```
JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration('
   alert(1);
   // more Javascript here
');
```

**File:**

```
JFactory::getDocument()->addScript(
    JUri::root() . 'templates/MY_TEMPLATE/js/file.js'
);
```

---

If this is for an extension if your own and you're importing a file, I'd suggest using the `JHtml` approach, as it will allow users to override the file , along with some other additional perks:

**Path to your JS file:**

> media/mod_something/js/file.js

**Code:**

```
JHtml::_('script', 'mod_something/file.js', array('version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true));
```

Notice that I'm using `'relative' => true` so the path can be shortened.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I've taken a look at the source and I'd argue that its a misuse of the docblock `@deprecated` tag within the core code. According to [phpDocumentor](http://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/deprecated.html), the `@deprecated` tag "_declares that the associated Structural elements will be removed in a future version_". Using `@deprecated` means that IDEs such as PHPStorm will warn about the usage of the method.

Comment: @Dom Normally I'd agree, however with something like this, Joomla didn't want to rename the function name, meaning backwards compatibility is kept, therefore they deprecated the way it's called, rather than the method itself.

Comment: By changing the method signature Joomla _has_ broken backwards compatibility. This is not how `@deprecated` is supposed to be used, phpDocumentor is very clear what it means and Joomla has used it incorrectly in this instance.

Comment: They havent broken BC cause the old approach still works in 3.x but will be removed in 4.0. Deprecated doesnt mean it doesnt work anymore

Comment: `@deprecated` means that '_the associated Structure elements will be removed in future versions_', not that that the method signature will change.

Comment: @Dom I'm fully aware of what it means :) Please read my first comment.